# Can I use external HDD with NTFS partitioning to regularly read/write on it with UBUNTU?

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs, external-hdd

I'm considering switching to UBUNTU from Windows 10 and I have two HDDs in a dock, that are partitioned as NTFS. They contain data that I use on a regular basis, such as Word files, PDFs etc. and I constantly add to them. What I'm actually wondering is can I use those HDDs with UBUNTU the same way that I used them with Windows 10?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: yes you can.

**Longer answer**: Ubuntu for a long time now supports reading and writing of ntfs formatted partitions out of the box (in contrast to for example Apple OS X). It also comes with file system repairing tools (`ntfsfix`).

*Small caveats*

- Because `ntfs` is a proprietary format, the only tools that can fully and comprehensively repair ntfs volumes are the Windows tools. Therefore, **do use the ntfs file format only when you wish ex-changeability with Windows**, and when you can connect the volume now and then to a Windows machine for checking the file system and keeping it healthy.
- Linux will only mount the drive read and write if the file system is *clean*. Therefore, always **fully disconnect the drive** while in Windows. For a removable drive, remove it using the tray icon. For an internal fixed drive, make sure Windows is shut down completely (i.e., no hibernation, no fast start) before accessing the drive in Linux.

Some explanation on fast start: Windows has a *fast start* feature that speeds up subsequent reboots. One of the tricks there is that the drives are not fully closed when Windows is closed. Thus, to seamlessly switch between Windows and Linux, make sure to disable the fast start feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but with a caveat: NTFS does not support Linux file permissions, and your Windows of course doesn't know your Linux user account.

But if you don't need either of that because you are only working alone with those documents (or all others working with them are equally trushtworthy), just go ahead and use those disks from both systems.